# Enabling Wake on Lan on Chromebook

Tags: wake-on-lan, chromebook

I have a Samsung 550 Chromebook plugged into a LAN via eth0.

I am trying to see if they support Wake on Lan. My tests show that they dont as they do not seem to respond when using a 3rd party utility to send the magic packet from another machine on the network but cannot find a definitive answer, so I am not sure if it is just a setting I need to enable?

Has anyone had any luck in using WOL on a Chromebook?

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up the terminal.
2. Once in the terminal type `set_wake_on_lan` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.